# Nginx "location ~ ." vs "location ~* \."

Tags: php, linux, nginx, server, nginx-location

Is there a difference between the 3 following directives?

```
location ~* \.(png)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}

location ~ \.(png)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}

location ~ .(png)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Thank you in advance for having taken the time thus far.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/801356/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-and-regexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are three forms of regular expression location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `~*` operator makes the test case insensitive.

The `.` character has a special meaning in a regular expression: matching any single character (much like `?` does in shell globs).

The `\.` sequence (an escaped dot) matches a literal dot character. This means the third example is probably not what you want (assuming you are attempting to match URIs ending with `.png`).

See [this document](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) for more on regular expressions.

Comment: Very much appreciated "Agent Smith"!